# How to remove connected apps from a google account using the Google API

Tags: google-api, google-oauth

I have created a custom app for my website.

How can I remove a connected custom apps from a Google account using a Google AP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is currently no API for programmaticly accessing what apps a user has connected to their Google account.

The only way to see and remove apps connected to your account is though the [Apps with access to your account](https://myaccount.google.com/permissions) page

## update

if this is your app and you have the access token for the user then you can remove their access via the [Revoke token](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/web-server#tokenrevoke) endpoint.

Comment: Welcome to stack remember to accept the answer if it helped you.

Comment: no you cant get all apps connected to a users account.  That imo would be a security nightmare

Comment: good afternoon, as of 21-04-2022, is it possible yet to achieve this @DaImTo?

Comment: if its your app and you have an access token for that user.  You could use the revoke endpoint to remove the users consent on the app.  Other then that no.

Comment: is there any documentation for that? i couldn't seeem to find that

Comment: [Revoke token](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/web-server#tokenrevoke)  it has to be an access token you send

Comment: Ok, thanks for the help! really greatfull for that